# How do I make a filter that applies white color?

Tags: javascript, image, colors, color-codes

So I am currently learning JavaScript and I am doing an exercise in uploading an image to a website and applying different sorts of filters on the image.

I am dane so I am trying to make a filter that applies a danish flag on the image, in the same way that we saw people applying french flags to their Facebook profile image a while back.

When I apply the red parts of the danish flag, it looks something like this:

```
function danish(){
for (var pixel of image2.values()){
   var avg = (pixel.getRed() + pixel.getGreen() + pixel.getBlue()) / 3; 

    if(pixel.getX()<0.3*image2.getWidth() && pixel.getY()<0.4*image2.getHeight()){
      if(avg < 128){
        pixel.setRed(2*avg);
        pixel.setGreen(0);
        pixel.setBlue(0);
      }
      else if(avg >= 128){
        pixel.setRed(255);
        pixel.setGreen(2*avg-255);
        pixel.setBlue(2*avg-255);
      }
    }
...
```

This part of the code works brilliantly as well as applying the remaining 3 squares of red. I also know how to address the specific pixels where the white color should go, but how do I make it whiter without making it a solid white?

Thanks in advance!